# Bing Ads Universal Event Tracking (Duplicate Goals / Conversions)

Tags: javascript, dom-events, pixel, bing, event-tracking

For those of you who aren't familiar with the Bing Ad platform its extremely similar to Google AdWords. As with all PPC networks, conversion tracking is a key component to any successful campaign.

In the past Bing used a simple IFRAME that allowed you to track when a customer visited your thank you page etc thus recording a conversion in your account.

On October 23, 2014 Bing Posted:

> We are pleased to announce the general availability of Universal Event
>   Tracking (UET) to our advertisers worldwide. UET provides a simple yet
>   powerful way to define and track goals (performance/conversion) that
>   are important for your business. With UET you can associate the
>   success of these goals with your advertising campaigns across
>   accounts, ad campaigns and devices.

The old pixel worked using an IFRAME that loaded a URL like this:

> http://flex.msn.com/mstag/tag/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/analytics.html?dedup=1&domainId=xxx&type=1&actionid=xxx

The new pixel uses a JavaScript event like this:

> var uetq = uetq || []; uetq.push({ 'ec':'click_test', 'ea':'1',
>   'el':'1', 'ev':'1', 'gv':'1' });

Apparently the new pixel functions as a multi-conversion...I've found that if you throw that on your thank you page and the user refreshes the page it would count an additional conversions. The old pixel didn't behave like that because of the "dedup=1" parameter.

Has anyone found a way to use the Bing UET Goal tracking on a unique conversions basis?

Comment: I am seeing duplicate conversions as well, between 5 and 11 so far. Bing Ads support cannot figure it out. I have even wrapped their code with my refresh proof logic and it still reports erroneous conversions. Did you solve this problem?